# PHP - Save value AND name using $_POST

Tags: php, html, post

I'm currently using the following format to save a value from an HTML form `$item_name=$_POST['item_name'];`

This saves the value, but how to I also save the name attribute in a variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Name attribute is key in $_POST

Comment: `$item_name_name = 'item_name'`?  Can you expand more on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm saving a lot of values and want to avoid typing each one out. I'm also adding them into an array right after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to store each element of $_POST variable as a key-value pair, then you can try:

```
$var = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
  $var[$key] = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm saving a lot of values and want to avoid typing each one out.

Please, make your mind first.
Global variables are *intended* to be typed by hand.
If you want some automated processing - just keep them in a form of array.

Looks like rdt.exe's answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

maye you noticed you have to use the name to access the `$_POST`-array and get the value. if you want to store the name in a variable, too, just do:

```
$item_name_name = 'item_name';
$item_name_value = $_POST[$item_name_name];
```

you *could* also use some kind of loop to dynamically create variables with the according names like this:

```
foreach( $_POST as $name => $value ){
    $$name = $value;
}
```

both ways are some kind of unnecessary and useless in my opinion, but you havn't stated what exactly you're trying to achive - so maybe this helps.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative approach:

```
$keysarray = array_keys ( $_POST);  
print_r( $keysarray);
```

This will give you all the keys in array

Answer (score -1):

The function you are looking for is called [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

This will create variables for all the `$key=>$val` pairs in the array.

```
$_EXAMPLE = array('bird' => 'chicken', 'dog' => 'greyhound');
export($_EXAMPLE);
echo $bird;  # prints "chicken"
echo $dog;   # prints "greyhound"
```

Watch out though - **this is a huge security risk**.  So are the solutions described in some of the other answers.

The problem with doing something like this is that a user can tamper with the POST data, and set parameters other than the ones she is supposed to set.  If they set variables that are actually variable names in your application, those variables can **be overwritten**.

```
$is_admin = false;
$_EXAMPLE = array('bird' => 'chicken', 'dog' => 'greyhound', 'is_admin' => 'true');
export($_EXAMPLE);

if ($is_admin) {  # this will now evaluate to true.
    # do sensitive stuff...
}
```